# What are the guidelines/ways to build optimized angular applications?

Tags: angular, typescript

This might be a broad question. But there has not been any resources which shows the correct way or better ways to build an angular application.

My question here is what are the suggest ways to build faster/better angular application to have better performance?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Are you referring just to the build process, or how to write the code? Do you mean faster to download to the client's browser, or faster to execute? What makes you think the way you're doing it now is not the correct way?

Comment: please dont close this question, it would help others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I will list down some of the tips/tricks that you can accomodate while you are building your angular application.Following are some of the tips that would make your angular app to run faster,

1. **Build the app using prod**
   ex:

   *- ng build --prod*

   *- ng build --prod --source-map*

   *-npx source-map-explorer main.bundle.js*
2. **Use Lazy Loading**

   - Download the only code needed to start the app
   - Use CanLoad guard to mediate navigation
   - Reload all the modules (except the ones protected by CanLoad) by using **`PreloadAllModules`** strategy

**3. Consider server-side rendering**

**4.Make each change detection faster**

**5.Use pure pipes instead of methods**

**`ex`**
*Calculated on every change detection*

```
<span>{{ relativeDate(tweet.createdAt) }}</span>
```

*Calculated only if the value was changed*

```
<span>{{ tweet.createdAt | relativeDate }}</span>
```

**6.Use trackBy in ngFor loops**

Also here are some of the [`guidelines`](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2018/08/angular-code-review-checklists-for.html) that you can follow while doing code review for your Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use lazy loading . By breaking into multiple modules .
2. Try to keep your App Module as slim as possible .
3. Try to use ServiceWoker to do background loading .
4. John Papa have a great documentation on Angular Guide lines . Read through them https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide